# Angular 4 watch two way binding property change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a `toggle-sorting` component which checks, if current sorting params are matching it's sorting slug, and handle clicks to output changes

```
// toggle-sorting.component.ts

@Input() sortingSlug: string;
@Input() currSorting: string;
@Output() currSortingChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

@HostBinding('class.sorting-asc') activeAsc: boolean;
@HostBinding('class.sorting-desc') activeDesc: boolean;

/**
 * Watch sorting params changes and update binding
 */
ngOnChanges() {
    this.activeDesc = this.currSorting === this.sortingSlug;
    this.activeAsc = this.currSorting === '-' + this.sortingSlug;
}

/**
 * Watch click event to set sorting
 */
@HostListener('click') setSorting() {
    if (this.activeDesc) {
        this.currSortingChange.emit('-' + this.sortingSlug);
    } else {
        this.currSortingChange.emit(this.sortingSlug);
    }
}
```

And I use it my parent component this way

```
// parent.component.html

// ... some layout
<th>
    <span toggle-sorting [(currSorting)]="sorting" sortingSlug="version">Scraper</span>
</th>
<th>
    <span toggle-sorting [(currSorting)]="sorting" sortingSlug="sites_count">Sites Scraped</span>
</th>
<th>
    <span toggle-sorting [(currSorting)]="sorting" sortingSlug="success_rate">Success rate</span>
</th>
// ... some layout
```

I have global `sorting` property in my parent component, which controls actual sorting param, which is two way binded to `toggle-sorting` children

```
// parent.component.ts

sorting: string = 'version';
```

I need to trigger api call each time global sorting param changes, but I cannot watch it with `ngOnChanges` as it's not @Input, I don't want to use `ngDoCheck` here as well (performancewise), and I do not want to use separate `@Input` and `@Output` in `toggle-sorting` (but for sure it will work for my purpose).

What is the best option in my case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few ways to do that.

1 . Using full `ngModel` format:

```
  (ngModelChange)="onSortChanged($event)" [ngModel]="sorting"

  public onSortChanged(value:string):void
  {
     const changed = this._sorting !== value;
     this._sorting = value;
     if(changed) {
       //... do smth
     }
  }
```

2 . Using `get`/`set`:

```
private _sorting:string;

public get sorting():string
{
    return this._sorting;
}

public set sorting(value:string)
{
    const changed = this._sorting !== value;
    this._sorting = value;
    if(changed) {
       this.onSortingChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. almost equal if I use separate `@Input` and `@Output` in toggle sorting 2. says I have no `_sorting` property in my component

Comment: Obviously you should add `private _currSorting:string` field to you component.